# My JTable is displaying empty rows with no data

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jtable

[Solved]

Before you read this, please go easy on me if I didn't ask the question properly or missed a few things. This is my first time asking a question on StackOverflow :)

I'm creating a Java Swing application that acts as a basic password manager for a college project and in the main application JFrame (after logging in), I'm trying to display a list of credential names and usernames in a JTable for the user to select from. The JTable displays the correct number of rows. However, all of the rows are empty.

I created 2 methods that deal with data retrieval.

- The method readCredentialLine(int lineNo) accesses a file called credentials.txt and returns the corresponding line to the line number specified in the method's parameters.
- The method modelCredentials(String email) uses the readCredentialLine method to obtain the credential names and usernames for a particular email address and put them into a 2D array. This array is the data for my JTable.

I put the modelCredentials method into a new DefaultTableModel object to represent the table's data.

I tested the readCredentialLine and modelCredentials methods and both return the correct output. I also tested the DefaultTableModel using the getDataVector() method and it displayed all of the data correctly.

I've been stuck trying to get the data displayed in the JTable properly for so long and would really appreciate some help  If anything's missing, just let me know and I'll edit my question to include it right away.

My code for the frame is shown below with a screenshot to make my question easier to understand.

[Main Application Window Screenshot with Empty Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/574Zc.png)

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

// Constructor for the main application screen

MainFrame(Account a) {
    retrieveAccountInfo(a);
    setLayoutManager();
    setLocationAndSize();
    addComponentsToContainer();
    addActionEvent();
}

// Method that retrieves the user's account information

private String accEmail;
private String accName;
private String accPass;

void retrieveAccountInfo(Account a) {
    accEmail = a.getEmail();
    accName = a.getName();
    accPass = a.getPassword();
}

// Initialization of an Account object to be used later on

Account acc = new Account(accName, accEmail, accPass);

// Initialization of the components of the main application screen

Container container = getContentPane();
JLabel greetingLabel = new JLabel("Welcome, ");
JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel(Account.class.getName());
JLabel passwordListLabel = new JLabel("My Vault");
JButton refreshButton = new JButton("Refresh");
JButton viewButton = new JButton("View");
JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
JButton editButton = new JButton("Edit");
JButton deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
JButton logoutButton = new JButton("Logout");

// Method to obtain credentials for a particular account from the credentials
// text file and create a model for the JTable

public String[][] modelCredentials(String email) {
    String[][] dataRetrieved = { { "", "" } };
    for (int i = 0; readCredentialLine(i + 1) != null; i++) {
        dataRetrieved = Arrays.copyOf(dataRetrieved, dataRetrieved.length + 1);
        String[] var = readCredentialLine(i + 1).split(":");
        if (var[0].equals(email)) {
            String[][] tempArr = { { var[1], var[2] } };
            dataRetrieved[i] = tempArr[0];
        }
    }
    return dataRetrieved;
}

// Method to read from the credential file
// Tested and working properly

public static String readCredentialLine(int lineNo) {
    File f = new File("src/files/credentials.txt");
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try (LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(br)) {
        String line = null;
        int lnum = 0;
        while ((line = lnr.readLine()) != null && (lnum = lnr.getLineNumber()) <= lineNo) {
            if (lnum == lineNo) {
                return line;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

// Creating and initializing the JTable and its model containing the credentials
// of the account owner

String[] columns = { "Credential Name", "Username" };
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(modelCredentials(accEmail), columns) {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }
};

JTable credentialTable = new JTable(model);
JScrollPane tableScroll = new JScrollPane(credentialTable);

// Method to set the layout of the main application screen to its default value

public void setLayoutManager() {
    container.setLayout(null);
}

// Method to define certain properties of components such as icons, location and
// size

public void setLocationAndSize() {
    greetingLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    greetingLabel.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    greetingLabel.setBounds(25, 25, 200, 50);
    nameLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    nameLabel.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    nameLabel.setBounds(125, 25, 200, 50);
    nameLabel.setText(accName);
    passwordListLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    passwordListLabel.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    passwordListLabel.setBounds(25, 75, 200, 50);
    tableScroll.setBounds(25, 125, 500, 325);
    refreshButton.setBounds(550, 125, 100, 30);
    viewButton.setBounds(550, 175, 100, 30);
    addButton.setBounds(550, 225, 100, 30);
    editButton.setBounds(550, 275, 100, 30);
    deleteButton.setBounds(550, 325, 100, 30);
    logoutButton.setBounds(550, 425, 100, 30);
}

// Method that adds all of the defined components to the container of the main
// application screen

public void addComponentsToContainer() {
    container.add(greetingLabel);
    container.add(nameLabel);
    container.add(passwordListLabel);
    container.add(tableScroll);
    container.add(refreshButton);
    container.add(viewButton);
    container.add(addButton);
    container.add(editButton);
    container.add(deleteButton);
    container.add(logoutButton);
}
```

Comment: Seems complicated because you try to increase the Array size for each row you read. A simple solution would be to NOT use an Array and instead use a Vector. If you read the API you can see that the DefaultTableModel can also be created with a Vector. Or you may want to check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64248097/how-do-i-read-separate-parts-from-a-txt-file-to-show-in-java-gui/64248188#64248188 which demonstrates how to read from a file directly into the TableModel.

Comment: I was able to fix my problem by using a vector instead of an array as you suggested. Thank you so much @camickr !!