# JTable not showing any information. Reading from a text file and adding it to a DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, file, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I am working on a Java Swing project and I am trying to understand how to use `JTable`.

I have a text file with a list of user information which is all separated by a comma without spaces. I am trying to get this information to be displayed in a table, however, when I run the form the table, it remains blank and never shows anything.

Here is my code:

```
private JTable listUsersTable;

// ...

String[] columnNames = {"USERNAME", "NAME", "SURNAME", "AGE", "SEX", "SITE"};

// Creates a table with the column names and zero rows.
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);

try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("userArchive.txt"));

    // Reads each line in the file "userArchive.txt", separates the data, and puts them into the table.
    String line = reader.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        String[] lineSplit = line.split(",");
        model.addRow(lineSplit);
        line = reader.readLine(); // Goes to the next line in the file.
    }
    reader.close();

    listUsersTable = new JTable(model);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e5) {
    e5.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

And here is my current JTable layout & settings using intelliJ's GUI designer:

[Image of my intelliJ GUI designer setup and the JTable in question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbylH.png)
(The JTable in the image is called `verUsuariosTable` however in the code this is called `listUsersTable`. This is because I am writing my code in Spanish but translating everything to ask the question).

Comment: I see where you create the table, but where do you add the table to a JScrollPane and where do you add the scroll pane to the frame? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64248097/how-do-i-read-separate-parts-from-a-txt-file-to-show-in-java-gui/64248188#64248188 for a complete working example.

Comment: @camickr I had no idea about the JScrollPane. Thank you. I used the link you sent me to figure out what I needed to add where. I'll. edit my question to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to include **JScrollPane** to the code. This link shows completely what is needed to work with text files and JTables.  ([How do I read separate parts from a txt File to show in Java GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64248097/how-do-i-read-separate-parts-from-a-txt-file-to-show-in-java-gui/64248188#64248188)).

I needed to add

```
listUsersTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(listUsersTable.getPreferredSize());
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(listUsersTable);
```

and then add the scrollPane to the panel I was working with using

```
currentPanel.add(scrollPane);
```